# How to Get the Value of field_code_file

Tags: 7

Considering that I know the NID of the node, how can I get the value of one of the field that belongs to that NID?

I tried everything I can to get the value of field_code_file with the following code:

```
$node = node_load($_GET['nid']);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$file = $wrapper->field_code_file->value();
```

The value returned by $file is "array". Here's the value:

```
Array ( [#theme] => field [#weight] => 0 [#title] => Code File [#access] => 1 [#label_display] => above [#view_mode] => _custom_display [#language] => und [#field_name] => field_code_file [#field_type] => file [#field_translatable] => 0 [#entity_type] => node [#bundle] => source_code [#object] => stdClass Object ( [vid] => 71 [uid] => 1 [title] => Billing Software [log] => You can now download the installer for Billing System. This is important if you don't have crystal reports v8.5 in your machine. [status] => 1 [comment] => 2 [promote] => 1 [sticky] => 0 [ds_switch] => [nid] => 29 [type] => source_code [language] => und [created] => 1227189989 [changed] => 1260934297 [tnid] => 0 [translate] => 0 [revision_timestamp] => 1260934297 [revision_uid] => 1 [body] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] =>

) ) ) [field_screenshot] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 36 [alt] => [title] => [width] => [height] => [uid] => 1 [filename] => Billing Screenshot.jpg [uri] => public://images/admin/Billing Screenshot.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 35357 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1227589659 ) ) ) [field_code_file] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 37 [display] => 1 [description] => [uid] => 1 [filename] => Billing System.zip [uri] => public://download/admin/Billing System.zip [filemime] => application/zip [filesize] => 864517 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1227589659 ) ) ) [field_terms_and_conditions] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1 ) ) ) [field_language] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 7 [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 7 [vid] => 5 [name] => Visual Basic [description] => [format] => [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => vocabulary_5 [metatags] => Array ( ) ) ) ) ) [field_tags] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 52 [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 52 [vid] => 10 [name] => visual basic [description] => [format] => [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => vocabulary_10 [metatags] => Array ( ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [tid] => 55 [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 55 [vid] => 10 [name] => billing [description] => [format] => [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => vocabulary_10 [metatags] => Array ( ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [tid] => 323 [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 323 [vid] => 10 [name] => cable tv [description] => [format] => [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => vocabulary_10 [metatags] => Array ( ) ) ) ) ) [metatags] => Array ( ) [cid] => 75722 [last_comment_timestamp] => 1386138557 [last_comment_name] => Legendx [last_comment_uid] => 0 [comment_count] => 442 [name] => admin [picture] => 1 [data] => a:7:{s:14:"picture_delete";i:0;s:14:"picture_upload";s:0:"";s:7:"contact";i:1;s:13:"form_build_id";s:37:"form-df16b3b26332f9a4dd7de12c3f483943";s:9:"nodewords";a:9:{s:8:"abstract";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:9:"canonical";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:9:"copyright";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:11:"description";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:8:"keywords";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:13:"revisit-after";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:1:"1";}s:6:"robots";a:2:{s:5:"value";a:6:{s:9:"noarchive";i:0;s:8:"nofollow";i:0;s:7:"noindex";i:0;s:5:"noodp";i:0;s:9:"nosnippet";i:0;s:6:"noydir";i:0;}s:11:"use_default";i:0;}s:8:"dc.title";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:8:"location";a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:0:"";s:9:"longitude";s:0:"";}}s:4:"info";s:106:"To receive an update on your email please enter your email at Feed subscription at the right of this page.";s:6:"format";s:1:"2";} [_field_view_prepared] => 1 [entity_view_prepared] => 1 [content] => Array ( ) ) [#items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 37 [display] => 1 [description] => [uid] => 1 [filename] => Billing System.zip [uri] => public://download/admin/Billing System.zip [filemime] => application/zip [filesize] => 864517 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1227589659 ) ) [#formatter] => file_default [0] => Array ( [#theme] => file_link [#file] => stdClass Object ( [fid] => 37 [display] => 1 [description] => [uid] => 1 [filename] => Billing System.zip [uri] => public://download/admin/Billing System.zip [filemime] => application/zip [filesize] => 864517 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1227589659 ) ) )
```

I am expecting a value like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/admin/Billing%20System.zip
```

I'm using this code in my simple module that I created.

For Jeet:

Thanks. When I use this command print_r($file), it returns this value:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 37 [display] => 1 [description] => [uid] => 1 [filename] => Billing System.zip [uri] => public://download/admin/Billing System.zip [filemime] => application/zip [filesize] => 864517 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1227589659 ) )
```

Now how can I get the full url like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/admin/Billing%20System.zip
```

I'm trying to understand what you mean by `file_create_url($uri)`, but I can't crack my head on it.

Can you please explain it to me further?

Thank you

Comment: Since you haven't shown what is failing, eg, what is being returned instead of what you are hoping for, perhaps http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/programatically-access-field-data-using-entitymetadatawrapper-drupal can shed some light on the various ways of doing this

Comment: Hi, I updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the field is a file type.

```
$node = node_load($_GET['nid']);
$file = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_code_file');
```

Print the `$file`. you will get a URI index. To get your full path to file use function `file_create_url($uri)`

Let me know if this doesn't get you the result.

Comment: Thank you. I almost there. I updated my post. Please try to look at it.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)